# Eclipse 4.7.3a and Java 10 Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse, javaw

I just installed a new Eclipse on my laptop with Windows 10 pro. Here is the Eclipse Version:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.  
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) Build id: 20180405-1200
```

My java version:

```
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)  
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

My test code:

```
package questions;  

public class TestMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

Command line execution under the test\bin directory created by Eclipse

```
java questions.TestMain
```

works fine.

But I can't get it work with in the Eclipse. Using "run as a java application" with

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1\javaw.exe
```

always produces the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class questions.TestMain  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: questions.TestMain
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The eclipse.ini specifies what is used to run Eclipse itself, it is nothing to do with what is used to run programs within Eclipse - that is configured in the ' Run > Run Configuration' for the program.

Comment: In Eclipse, a Java application will be launched with a separate JRE/JDK. In _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ the JREs/JDKs can be specified from which you can then choose in the run/debug configuration (_JRE_ tab).

Comment: @greg-449  , you are right. It needs to be configured in Run Configuration.

Comment: Greg and @howlger , do you have any suggestions about "Could not find or load main class" problem? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the existing run configuration is broken. Does deleting the run configuration and running again via _Run As > Java Application_ solve the problem?

Comment: @howlger I tried to delete and rerun, didn't help.

Comment: Just an idea: in _Window > Preferences: Java_ click _Rebuild Index_ button (maybe the Java index is broken).

Comment: @howlger Many thanks for your suggestions. Turned out the Eclipse workspace is under the directory with non ascii characters.  Even though within the workspace everything seemed fine, the javaw.exe couldn't reach the bin directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the Eclipse workspace is under the directory with non ascii characters. Even though within the workspace everything (creating the project, compiling, etc) seemed fine, javaw.exe couldn't reach the bin directory.

Comment: Which non-ASCII character?

Comment: @howlger Chinese encoding